# Reading switches with no common ground on Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: button, raspberry-pi-pico

I have been trying to use a four-button PCB I had lying around in my house for one of my projects with a Raspberry Pi Pico. The problem is that I have never worked with such a layout that doesn't use a common ground for the buttons.

This is the PCB:

[image]

And this is a schematic I drew of it:

[image]

How can I interface with this PCB and know which button is being pressed in code?

Comment: The buttons are in a 2x2 matrix. Pin 1 is the first row, pin 2 the second. Redraw you schematic to reflect this so it is easier to read. To read the keypad requires a little bit code to read each row and then split out the column bits. The gpio you require is two outputs and two inputs.

Comment: That helps me visualize this better. I will try to redraw it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How can I interface with this PCB and know which button is being
> pressed in code?*

- 2 dedicated inputs with pull-downs connected to pins 3 and 4
- 2 outputs that output a logic "1" pulse alternately and sequentially on pins 1 and 2
- When one output is outputting a "1" the other output is set to be high impedance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWgU9m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've chosen 1 kΩ resistors because many inexpensive tactile buttons need a decent wetting current for them to be effective in operation. You may get away with a higher value like 10 kΩ

Writing the code is down to you.

Answer (score 4):

Not to detract from @Andy aka's answer.

Here is an alternative algorithm, which will not offer an advantage for a 2X2 set of buttons, but will reduce the scan time for, say, a computer keyboard. It adds another step to determine which columns to scan:

1. Set rows as outputs, columns as inputs
2. Output 1s to all rows,
3. Read and record the column data.
4. Set the columns to outputs, rows to inputs
5. Sequentially output the recorded data, bit by bit, 1s only, back to the column pins.
6. Read and record the row data.

Gold switch contacts can work down to 1 microamp and so can function with microcontroller internal pulldown resistors. Silver contacts (down to 1milliamp) and other contact materials will need external resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fviyjQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>